# Problema con los DropDownList en ASP.net

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

Contexto: Cree una pagina con un formulario que servirá para editar "lectores"
extraigo el ID de los lectores de un Gridview y paso ese ID a la pagina donde realizare la edición del editor el problema esta es que cuando hago la consulta a la base de datos, me trae los datos pero los datos que deseo ingresar en los DropDownList que tengo en el formulario me los trae en "-1" y no entiendo por que esta haciendo eso, además, debido a esto, tira error

codigo Aspx:

```
  public void LLenoLector()
        {
            Decimal IDLector = 0;
            IDLector = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["ID"]);
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            if (PrepararAcceso.ObtenerDatos("SELECT LECTORES.DIRLEC AS DIRECCION,LECTORES.TELLEC AS TELEFONO, LECTORES.ESCLEC AS ESCUELA, LECTORES.CURLEC AS CURSO, EJEMPLAR.TITLIB AS ULTIMO, LECTORES.DEVUELTO AS DEVUELTO, PAR1.par_des_par AS COMUNA,PAR2.par_des_par AS CIUDAD,PAR3.par_des_par AS ESTADO FROM LECTORES LEFT OUTER JOIN PAR AS PAR1 ON PAR1.par_cod_tab = 2 AND PAR1.par_cod_par = LECTORES.COMLEC LEFT OUTER JOIN PAR AS PAR2 ON PAR2.par_cod_tab = 4 AND PAR2.par_cod_par = LECTORES.CIULEC LEFT OUTER JOIN PAR AS PAR3 ON PAR3.par_cod_tab = 7 AND PAR3.par_cod_par = LECTORES.EDOLEC LEFT JOIN EJEMPLAR ON EJEMPLAR.CODLIB = LECTORES.ULTLIB WHERE LECTORES.RUTLEC = '" + IDLector + "'", ref ds, MasterPage.CadenaConexion.ToString())) 
            {
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) 
                {
                    txtdireccion.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DIRECCION"].ToString();
                    txttelefono.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["TELEFONO"].ToString();
                    txtescuela.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ESCUELA"].ToString();
                    txtescuela.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CURSO"].ToString();
                    DropUltimo.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ULTIMO"].ToString();
                    txtdevuelto.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DEVUELTO"].ToString();
                    DropCiudad.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CIUDAD"].ToString();
                    DropComuna.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["COMUNA"].ToString();
                    DropEstado.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ESTADO"].ToString();
                
                }
            }

        }
```

Asi quedan los DropDownList
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el error que arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por si no se logro entender, lo que estoy tratando de realizar es que se pueda editar lo relacionado al ID del lector, el cual cuando doy a editar entramos con el ID a la pagina que se encarga de esto, en esta tengo albergada Textboxs y DropDownlists, de los cuales los deseo tener llenos con la consulta que estoy realizando y me genera el error presentado,
Espero puedan ayudarme!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo correcto sería obtener el id del estado y asignarlo al ddl:

```
DropEstado.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID_ESTADO"].ToString();
```

Pero si lo deseas hacer con el texto, intenta hacerlo así:

```
DropEstado.Items.FindByText(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]"ESTADO"].ToString()).Selected=true;
```

Comment: Intente hacerlo de las dos formas, la primera que me mencionas la habia implementado, pero, me sigue trayendo los ddl en -1 y ahora vi la segunda forma y me arroja error.